# AngularJs & Flask: Form template

Tags: angularjs, flask, blogs

I am following the tutorial Building a blog using Flask and AngularJs (http://tutsbucket.com/tutorials/building-a-blog-using-flask-and-angularjs-part-1/) by John Kevin Basco. 
I have followed all the steps and the only thing left to do is write form templates. This is what I have so far:

```
<form ng-submit="submit(isValid,user)" ng-model="user">
<h3>Email address</h3>
<input name="email" type="email" type="submit" ng-model="user.email" value="Enter email">
<h3>Password</h3>
<input name="password" type="password" ng-model="user.password" type="submit">
<h3>Confirm password</h3>
<input name="password" type="password" ng-model="user.passwordConfirmation" type="submit">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This lets me call the submit function with the correct user object. I also tried writing adding an action call here to POST straight to the server, which successfully created accounts but redirected me to server location without any possibilty of getting back to client.

This is my controller:

```
Blog.controller('UserCreateCtrl', function($scope, User) {

    var defaultForm = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        passwordConfirmation: ''
    };

    $scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);

    $scope.submit = function(isValid, user) {
        console.log(user);
        $scope.submitted = true;
        $scope.accountCreated = false;

        $scope.userCreateForm.$setDirty();

        if (!isValid) {
            return;
        }

        User.create(user).then(function(response) {
            $scope.accountCreated = true;

            // reset form
            $scope.submitted = false;
            $scope.user = angular.copy(defaultForm);
            $scope.userCreateForm.$setPristine();
        });
    };
})
```

Upon submitting, I get "cannot $setDirty of undefined", so the problem is that userCreateForm is undefined.

UserCreateForm is found here in the server:

```
class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

If anyone has a clue on the correct way to write the CreateUser template form, I ,along with the multitude of users who have been asking for the last part the last 6 months, would much appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

`UserCreateForm` is a Python class, and has nothing to do with your javascript/angularJS code. As a side note, `UserCreateForm` amd `userCreateForm` are different identifiers as both Python and Javascript are case sensitive. I skimmed the tutorial and nowhere is `userCreateForm` defined in Javascript. I think that the author's auto-complete may have been a little overzealous, and what you actually want is `$scope.user.$setPristine();`. I have not tested this but I would give it a shot.